# NullPointerException in asynktask while settext

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview, nullpointerexception, settext

I have Asynctask in my activity. The problem is when I setText in onPostExecute() it gave me NullPointerException. the textview in a custom dialog XML. I tried to put the TextView variable as a global but it's the same thing. The toast is working fine. This is my code:

```
private class LikeDislike extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json;
            json = userFunction.likeDislike(params[0]);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            super.onPostExecute(json);

            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    //registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        String like = json.getString("like");
                        String disLike = json.getString("dislike");
                        TextView likeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.likenumber);
                        TextView dislikeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dislikenumber);
                        likeText.setText(like);
                        dislikeText.setText(disLike);
                        //TODO
                    }else{      
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "error in parsing", duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: did you call setContentView() before this?

Comment: Yes I did but the dialog has a different XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying the TextViews are in your Dialog then you have to call myDialog.findViewById() to get the views.
Otherwise findViewById() try to find it in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView likeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.likenumber);
 TextView dislikeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dislikenumber);
```

this should be defined in your `Oncreate()` Method after Setting your xml file through `setcontentview()`.

Comment: Should, maybe, but not necessary and probably not returning the Null Exception.

Comment: Still the same problem Null Exception @Asok

Answer (score 0):

It's returning null because you're not asking the right component to `findViewById(int)`

You have to do it while inflating your custom XML, inside the onCreateDialog (or something similar. That View that you're setting to be the dialog layout, you have to ask that view to `findViewById()` and then your TextView will be there.

Answer (score 0):

firstly the id R.id.likenumber and R.id.dislikenumber should be there in your xml which you have in setContentView and if your using 
Custom XML for Dialog then make use of

```
  TextView likeText = (TextView) YOURDIALOG.findViewById(R.id.likenumber);
  TextView dislikeText = (TextView) YOURDIALOG.findViewById(R.id.dislikenumber);
  likeText.setText(like);
  dislikeText.setText(disLike);
```